# Unable to upgrade - "A dependency job for netfilter-persistent.service failed."

Tags: upgrade

When running "apt-get upgrade" I get:

```
Setting up netfilter-persistent (1.0.3) ...
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
A dependency job for netfilter-persistent.service failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript netfilter-persistent, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing package netfilter-persistent (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of iptables-persistent:
 iptables-persistent depends on netfilter-persistent (= 1.0.3); however:
  Package netfilter-persistent is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package iptables-persistent (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates it's a follow-up error from a previous failure.
                                                                                                            Errors were encountered while processing:
 netfilter-persistent
 iptables-persistent
```

Here is what "journalctl -xn" returns:

```
-- Logs begin at Thu 2016-09-15 13:21:08 CEST, end at Fri 2016-10-28 11:41:56 CEST. --
Oct 28 11:41:56 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Starting Load Kernel Modules...
-- Subject: Unit systemd-modules-load.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit systemd-modules-load.service has begun starting up.
Oct 28 11:41:56 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd-modules-load[9237]: could not open moddep file '/lib/modules/3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64/modules.dep.bin'
Oct 28 11:41:56 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd-modules-load[9237]: Failed to lookup alias 'fuse': Function not implemented
Oct 28 11:41:56 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Oct 28 11:41:56 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Failed to start Load Kernel Modules.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-modules-load.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit systemd-modules-load.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Oct 28 11:41:56 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Dependency failed for netfilter persistent configuration.
-- Subject: Unit netfilter-persistent.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit netfilter-persistent.service has failed.
--
-- The result is dependency.
Oct 28 11:41:56 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Job netfilter-persistent.service/start failed with result 'dependency'.
Oct 28 11:41:56 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: Unit systemd-modules-load.service entered failed state.
Oct 28 11:41:56 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx systemd[1]: systemd-modules-load.service failed.
Oct 28 11:41:56 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx polkitd(authority=local)[1958]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:9232:370925565 (system bus
```

It's running on an OVH dedicated server. And uname -r returns:

```
3.14.32-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64
```

Comment: Reproduced on a Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I had the same problem on a Raspberry Pi 3 and the issue/solution was described here: https://discourse.osmc.tv/t/failed-to-start-load-kernel-modules/3163/14